# std::string empties when printing new line

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following code sample,

```
std::string comment;
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    char buff[500];
    sprintf_s(buff, "%i %e ", intv, dbl);
    comment.append(buff);

    comment.append("random");
    comment =+ '\n'; //c1

    //comment.append("random2"); //c2
}

cout << comment;
```

now, if I run this code nothing is displayed in the output window, but if I comment c1 then the output is displayed. And if I uncomment c1 and c2 both then only the text "random2" is displayed (this is printed only once),

Now my problem is how do I add add a new line to my code without breaking it. I cannot use osstream because of performance issues.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no `=+` operator

Comment: I wonder why this was close-voted "off-topic".

Comment: Perhaps the voter felt it was just a simple typo and therefore too obvious. I disagree: this question has depth and is well-posed. Actually, just given it +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=+` is not a append operator but rather assignment with operand with unary plus.

You may change that to `+=`, which is the append operator for string.

Answer (score 5):

```
comment =+ '\n';
```

This really is

```
comment = +'\n';
```

The unary `+` is practically a no-op (except the operand may be converted from `char` to `int`), but a valid operator. This means you are simply assigning a `char` or `int` to a `std::string`, setting `comment` to just '\n'.

Use `operator+=` instead to push back onto the `std::string`.

Comment: +1, but strictly speaking `+'\n'` *promotes* '\n' to an `int` type so is not a no-op.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, when I try to compile OP's code, it gives a `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’` on that line because of that. How did he get it to compile?

Comment: The cynic in me is suspecting a contrived question. It *would* have compiled if `comment` was a `std::basic_string<int32_t>` but since the edit, we know the type.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I am not sure, `The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or pointer type and the
result is the value of the argument.`, then `Integral and floating types are collectively called arithmetic
types.`, then `There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”,`, then `For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (...) standard un-
signed integer type: “unsigned char”,`, then `, a plain char object can take on either the same values as a signed char or an unsigned char;
which one is implementation-defined.`

Comment: ... To me this sounds like unary operator+ is well defined for chars.

Comment: Hum. Am I confusing myself with C? But what about @RedAlert's compile error which is exactly what I would have expected?

Comment: In C we have `The result of the unary + operator is the value of its (promoted) operand. The integer
promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.`, then `The type char, the signed and unsigned integer types`, and `integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types`. Unfortunately, I lack the time to really enlighten us on this :P I'll ask the compiler -- edit: g++ gives me type char for a character literal, and type int for a unary+plused char literal. He agrees with you :)

Comment: @RedAlert: It certainly should compile, converting the value back to `char` to use `basic_string::operator=(charT)`. Perhaps you've got a dodgy library that's missing that operator.